# Copiar texto de un input o un div en el porta papeles guardando las etiquetas HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hace un tiempo podía copiar texto de un input text o un div en el portapales, guardando también su formato HTML. Es decir, podía copiar el texto con las etiquetas HTML que tuviere tales como `p`, `strong`, `em`, `h1`... etc.

Para ello usaba la librería [Zeroclipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org) y todo funcionaba de maravilla.

Usaba el código como explica Zeroclipboard en [Github](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard), aunque introduciendo el contenido en un input text:

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    <script src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
// main.js
var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button") );

client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
  // alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

  client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
    // `this` === `client`
    // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
    event.target.style.display = "none";
    alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"] );
  } );
} );
```

El hecho es que ahora no logro hacerlo funcionar de ninguna manera. Tengo subido en la carpeta del HTML los archivos `ZeroClipboard.swf`, `ZeroClipboard.js`, `main.js`...

**Quiero hacerlo funcionar en Safari** y mi sistema operativo es **Mac OSX Sierra**. No sé si el no funcionamiento de debe a Safari o al hecho de que he actualizado a Sierra, pues el anterior código funcionaba en otra versión del Sistema Operativo.

**¿Alguien tiene funcionando esta librería en Safari?**

O, **¿podrían recomendarme otra librería alternativa?**

O, **¿es posible hacer esto con Javascript / jQuery sin pasar por una librería?**

---

### EDIT

Se trataría de tener texto como este en un `div` o en un `input`:

```
<div id="content">
<p>Este es un párrafo</p>
<p>Este es otro con letras en <em>cursiva</em>, en <strong>negritas</strong>
<br />Y además como saltos de línea</p>
</div>
```

Y que al hacer clic en el botón `Copiar` me copie el mismo contenido, incluyendo sus respectivas etiquetas HTML. O... más avanzado aún, aunque eso podría hacerlo (creo) ... que al llenar el `div` o el `input` con contenido, lo copie también en el portapapeles.

La respuesta de @Carmen, más abajo, ejecuta la acción de copiar, pero obtiene el texto sin las etiquetas HTML. Yo necesito el texto íntegro para introducirlo en una base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nueva forma

Usando [`Clipboard API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

> La API del portapapeles brinda la capacidad de responder a los comandos del portapapeles (cortar, copiar y pegar), así como de leer y escribir de forma asincrónica en el portapapeles del sistema. El acceso al contenido del portapapeles está cerrado detrás de la API de permisos: el permiso de escritura del portapapeles se otorga automáticamente a las páginas cuando están en la pestaña activa. Se debe solicitar el permiso de lectura del portapapeles, lo que puede hacer al intentar leer los datos del portapapeles.

Ejemplo:

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  const type = 'text/plain';
  const blob = new Blob([text], {type});
  let data = [new ClipboardItem({[type]: blob})];

  navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(function() {
    console.log('Copiado!')
  }, function() {
    console.log('Ups! No se copio');
  });
}

//
document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', function() {
  copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Este es un párrafo</p>
  <p>Este es otro con letras en <em>cursiva</em>, en <strong>negritas</strong>
    <br />Y además como saltos de línea</p>
</div>
<button type="button" id="copy">Copiar</button>
```

***PD**: En el "snippet" no funciona por restricciones de sandbox.*

---

### Forma vieja

Si lo que necesitas es copiar el contenido `HTML` de un elemento o el `value` de un `input`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Crear un `textarea`. (1)
- Guardar en el mismo el texto a copiar. (2)
- Seleccionar el contenido del mismo. (3)
- Copiar el texto seleccionado. (4)

Ejemplo:

```js
function copyToClipboard(txt) {
  if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
    // Ref 1
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    // Ref 2
    textarea.textContent = txt;
    // Evita scroll al elemento en Edge
    textarea.style.position = "fixed";
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    // Ref 3
    textarea.select();
    // Algunos navegadores pueden lanzar una excepción de seguridad
    try {
        // Ref 4
        return document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (ex) {
        console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
        return false;
    } finally {
        document.body.removeChild(textarea);
    }
  }
}

//
document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', function() {
  copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="content">
<p>Este es un párrafo</p>
<p>Este es otro con letras en <em>cursiva</em>, en <strong>negritas</strong>
<br />Y además como saltos de línea</p>
</div>
<button type="button" id="copy">Copiar</button>
```

Comment: +1 !Geeeeenial! Excepto lo de `Copar` en el nombre del botón. ¡Muchísimas gracias! Aunque por algún motivo me copia una línea en blanco al principio del texto. ¿Sabrías a qué se debe?

Comment: @A.Cedano, jajajaja. Con respecto a la linea en blanco, es el salto de linea entre el `<div id="content">` y el primer `<p>`. Se le puede hacer un `trim` si es algo que no te gustaria tener.

Answer (score 1):

Te paso un enlace que creo puede resolver bien tu pregunta.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36640126/5675636

Copiado de la respuesta de @EldoNewAge

```
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
if (document.selection) { 
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("Copy"); 

} else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
     range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
     window.getSelection().addRange(range);
     document.execCommand("Copy");
     alert("text copied") 
}}
```

Comment: Gracias. La función de copiar al portapapeles la hace. Pero no me obtiene el texto con las etiquetas HTML. Si pongo el texto siguiente un `div`: `<p>Este es un párrafo</p><p>Este es otro con letras en <em>cursiva</em>, en <strong>negritas</strong><br />Y además como saltos de línea</p>` cuando le doy a copiar lo hace, pero no me obtiene las etiquetas `p`, `em`, `strong`, etc.