# Problema al copiar al portapapeles con clipboard.js

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy intentando que se copie el contenido de una celda de una tabla mediante un botón con JavaScript y la librería `clipboard.js`

Cada celda tiene un valor diferente y ese valor llega con PHP en un `foreach` y se muestra con `$item->resultado`. El problema es que esa variable es un String que contiene un json en un formato similar a este:

```
[{"_id":"5a5c9ed7f59787032fff7bba","index":0,"guid":"8171d24e-e8ed-43d6-a115-229390f8a8d2","isActive":false,"balance":"$2,158.78","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":31,"eyeColor":"blue","name":"Dianna Gonzales","gender":"female","company":"DATACATOR","email":"diannagonzales@datacator.com","phone":"+1 (958) 555-2659","address":"614 Conduit Boulevard, Catharine ... }]
```

**Creo que mi problema viene con las comillas, ya que solo se queda copiado hasta donde se encuentra con las primeras, es decir, copia:** `[{`

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Os dejo mi código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.info('Accion:', e.action);
    console.info('Texto:', e.text);
    console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
    alert();
    alert();
    alert();
    e.clearSelection();
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('Accion:', e.action);
    console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
</script>
    <?php $resultado = [{"_id":"5a5c9ed7f59787032fff7bba","index":0,"guid":"8171d24e-e8ed-43d6"}];
    ?>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="<?php $resultado; ?>">Copiar texto</button>
```

Comment: Yo usaba antes una librería, pero ahora uso [esta función, que es muy sencilla, te comparto el enlace a la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78500/29967), por si te puede servir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro. Ten en cuenta que el valor del atributo `data-clipboard-text` se encierra entre comillas dobles. En cuanto encuentra otra comilla doble interpreta que ahí finaliza el valor del atributo.

Deberías "escapar" las comillas dobles en el valor como `&quot;`.

Mira qué resultado daría tal y como lo tienes (primer botón) y escapando las comillas (segundo botón):

```js
$(function(){
  console.log('Primer botón: ', $('.btn').data('clipboard-text'));
  console.log('Segundo botón: ', $('.btn2').data('clipboard-text'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="[{"_id":"5a5c9ed7f59787032fff7bba","index":0,"guid":"8171d24e-e8ed-43d6"}]">Copiar texto</button>

<button class="btn2" data-clipboard-text="[{&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;5a5c9ed7f59787032fff7bba&quot;,&quot;index&quot;:0,&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;8171d24e-e8ed-43d6&quot;}]">Copiar texto</button>
```