# Código javascript no se ejecuta en internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html

soy muy novato en javascript pero he conseguido realizar el siguiente html con 5 botones, al clicar en un botón se copia un texto oculto en el portapapeles, el problema es que no me funciona en internet explorer 11 y no se por que, no consigo realizar nada, he usado el código del siguiente post: [Copiar texto de un input o un div en el porta papeles guardando las etiquetas HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78479/copiar-texto-de-un-input-o-un-div-en-el-porta-papeles-guardando-las-etiquetas-ht)

y el código que tengo es esto:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<body>
 <button type="button" id="tpcentraldb">TPCentralDB</button>
 <button type="button" id="tpposdb">TPPosDB</button>
 <button type="button" id="dbhipos">DBhiPOS</button>
 <button type="button" id="tptextdb">TPTextDB</button>
 <button type="button" id="tpcmdb">TPCMDB</button>
 
 <div id="content" style="visibility:hidden">TEXTO
Para
Apartado
tpcentraldb</div>
 <div id="content1" style="visibility:hidden">TEXTO
Para
Apartado
tpposdb</div>
 <div id="content2" style="visibility:hidden">TEXTO
Para
Apartado
dbhipos</div>
 <div id="content3" style="visibility:hidden">TEXTO
Para
Apartado
tptextdb</div>
 <div id="content4" style="visibility:hidden">TEXTO
Para
Apartado
tpcmdb</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function copyToCliboard(txt) {
    if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
   var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
   textarea.textContent = txt;
   textarea.style.position = "fixed";
   document.body.appendChild(textarea);
   textarea.select();
   try {
    return document.execCommand("copy");
   } catch (ex) {
    console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
    return false;
   } finally {
    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
   }
    }
  }
  //
  document.getElementById('tpcentraldb').addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyToCliboard(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
  });
  //
  document.getElementById('tpposdb').addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyToCliboard(document.getElementById('content1').innerHTML);
  });
  //
  document.getElementById('dbhipos').addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyToCliboard(document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML);
  });
  //
  document.getElementById('tptextdb').addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyToCliboard(document.getElementById('content3').innerHTML);
  });
  //
  document.getElementById('tpcmdb').addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyToCliboard(document.getElementById('content4').innerHTML);
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

He usado este código porque necesito que me respete los saltos de línea, el único problema que tengo esque no me funciona en internet explorer 11, el cual lo necesito también.

Me podéis ayudar?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Revisa la consola de desarrollador en IE11. Es probable que ahí se indique un mensaje de error.

Answer (score 2):

**Explicando un poco el porque del problema.** *(Se aplica para los js que en general no funcionan en IE)*

El código trabaja directamente con los atributos de los elementos html. Esto funciona muy bien en todos los navegadores menos en IE. Esto se debe a la carencia de soporte en IE, al punto de que no pueden modificarse atributos directamente desde javascript (`document.getElementById("id").atributo="valor";` no funciona).

**La solución**

Utiliza css para ocultar el texto y en js la función `className` la cual si es soportada en IE (afortunadamente).

El código queda de esta forma (y esta probado en IE 11):

```js
function copiar(id) {
    /* Obtener el campo */
    var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
    
    /* Hacerlo visible */
    document.getElementById(id).className="";

    /* Selccionar el texto */
    copyText.select();

    /* Copiar el texto seleccionado */
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    
    /* Hacer invisible el texto */
    document.getElementById(id).className="hide";

    /* Puedes comentar esta alerta */
    alert("Texto Copiado: " + copyText.value);
  }
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="copiar('tpcentraldb')" >TPCentralDB</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="copiar('tpposdb')">TPPosDB</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="copiar('dbhipos')">DBhiPOS</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="copiar('tptextdb')">TPTextDB</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="copiar('tpcmdb')">TPCMDB</button>
  
  <textarea class="hide" id="tpcentraldb" >TEXTO1
Para
Apartado
tpcentraldb</textarea>
  <textarea class="hide" id="tpposdb"  >TEXTO2
Para
Apartado
tpposdb</textarea>
  <textarea class="hide" id="dbhipos"  >TEXTO3
Para
Apartado
dbhipos</textarea>
  <textarea class="hide" id="tptextdb"  >TEXTO4
Para
Apartado
tptextdb</textarea>
  <textarea class="hide" id="tpcmdb"  >TEXTO5
Para
Apartado
tpcmdb</textarea>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda y a todos lo que tienen problemas similares, saludos.