# Convertir texto plano a HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me pueden ayudar con el siguiente problema que tengo.

Tengo cierto texto que se puede modificar dentro de un `div`, lo que no he podido lograr es crear una función que me devuelva algo como lo siguiente:

```
<div><p style="font-size: 14px;">TEST</p></div>
```

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor la pregunta muestra los tu html sera mas facil responderte

Comment: para editar tu pregunta has clic [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/96198)

Comment: Podrías adjuntar lo que has intentado hacer hasta ahora o crear un ejemplo?

Comment: ¿No será [algo así o parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78479/29967) lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Tengo un div de la siguiente manera:

 <div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 tags buttons"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_text" class="row" contentEditable="true" style=" border : 1px solid; ">
           PRUEBA <br />
        </div>
 </div>

 El div "div_text" es donde voy a introducir texto,
 Lo que deseo es que al darle click en un boton es convertir todo el contenido del div
 en html con saltos de linea, etiquetas, algo similar a esto



 <div><p style='font-size : 14;'>PRUEBA</p><BR /></div>

Comment: Hola! Por favor termina el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y revisa [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Lo importante siempre es que muestres que has intentado y si es posible crea un [mcve]

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78479/copiar-texto-de-un-input-o-un-div-en-el-porta-papeles-guardando-las-etiquetas-ht    es parecido a lo que quiero hacer, solo que de manera inversa, obtener el codigo html del texto con tags y todo lo que implica

Comment: Para agregar información a la pregunta puedes darle click al enlace de [edit]

Comment: Lo que pretendo es como este ejemplo

https://wordtohtml.net/

en el lado derecho se visualiza el resultado de lo que se escribe en el lado izquierdo

Comment: Entonces ya pudiste generar todo el contenido en un input pero ahora al querer mostrarlo en tu `div`, en vez de mostrar todo el html (eso que está en la pregunta) te muestra sólo el texto?

Comment: Asi es, solamente me muestra el texto tal cual, lo que necesito es el html de ese texto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función outerHTML() de jquery:

```
$('#div_text')[0].outerHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no te entendí mal, cosa que *es posible*

Usando **jQuery** podes vaciar el `div` con `.empty()` y luego agregarle el nuevo html con un `.append()`

Por ejemplo;

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){

    var a = "<div><p style='font-size: 14px; color:red;'>TEST</p></div>";
         
         $('#div_text').empty();
         $('#div_text').append(a);
});
```

```html
     <div id="div_text" class="row" contentEditable="true" style=" border : 1px solid; "> PRUEBA <br /> </div>

<button>Modificar</button>

     <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Estaría bueno, que para próximas preguntas, intentes formularlas de manera más clara, porque si la solución es la que planteo, lo más complejo de brindarte la ayuda es interpretar lo que necesitabas!

**EDIT**

En caso contrario, si lo que necesitas es obtener el `html` ubicado dentro de un `div`, podes usar `.html()`

Por ejemplo;

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){

alert($('.prueba').html());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prueba">
<p style="color:red;">
Prueba!
</p>
</div>
<button>
Botón
</button>
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que al modificar el texto en el input genera un html de la siguiente manera `<div><p style="font-size: 14px;">TEST</p></div>`, entonces una vez que tengas eso, podrías mostrarlo con la función `text()` de jQuery, por ejemplo:

```js
$('textarea').val('TEST');

// suponemos que esto te devuelve parseado el html
var textarea = '<div><p style="font-size: 14px;">TEST</p></div>';


$('#mostrarhtml code').text(textarea);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>

<div id="mostrarhtml">
  <code></code>
</div>
```

Comment: Eso es lo que busco, solo que no puedo obtener es esta parte :


var textarea = '<div><p style="font-size: 14px;">TEST</p></div>';

Comment: No dijiste que en la pregunta ya tenías ese dato?

Comment: No, solo lo puse como ejemplo, pero eso es lo que requiero

Answer (score 0):

Solo utiliza el elemento HTML `<Code>`

```js
var div_entrada = document.getElementById('div_entrada'); 
  document.getElementById("btnMostrar").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
  var htmlText = div_entrada.innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "";  document.getElementById('result').append(htmlText)
  }, false);
```

```css
code {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id='div_entrada' style="border-style:solid;">
<p>Parraflo</p>
<ul>
    <li>Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
    <li>Cuatro</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Mostrar" id="btnMostrar"/>
<br>
<br>
<div  style="border-style:solid;">
<code width="50%" id="result">
</code>
</div>
```

[Element/Code  MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code)